# CentOS - XServer, VNC, Display conflict

Tags: ssh, centos, vnc

Here's what I want to do:
I need to set up this computer so that the physical output display, via the primary display port, is duplicated when someone connects via vnc.

Here's the problem:
I can connect via SSH to the computer with no problems. I can also connect via VNC to the computer without problems.
But the physical display displays the following error after showing the CL login prompt.

> Failed to start the xserver(your graphics interface). It is likely that it is not set up correctly. Would you like to view the x server output to diagnose the problem.

Now, I don't have physical access to the machine, so I can't select yes of no. naturally, neither SSH nor VNC connections provide me with that screen.

What I've tried:
Uninstalling / Reinstalling VNC
Uninstalling / Reinstalling XServer
(Yes, I do come from a Windows background).

Basically, I need to get this screen showing the same as the VNC connection does.

Any ideas?
I'm happy to try almost anything that does not require physical machine access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might want something like this: http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/x11vnc+setup

Comment: This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Deconfigure the VNC server and instead load the `vnc` module in the Xorg config.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but David's solution worked perfectly.